# Propagate events in java

Tags: java, events

If we have a class in Java responsilbe for building interfaces (builder), it builds an interface which the user interacts with (interface 1 )and the user clicks a button which does some processing using a calculation class.

Is there anyway of knowing when this processing is complete from the builder class so it can proceed to build the second interfce and hide/close the original?

I was thinking the interface could throw an event which can be listended for in the interface builder class.

Is there a more appropriate way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) class should just build.

If you need something to listen for events and react by hiding or closing something and building something else, that sounds much more like a controller in [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) or a related pattern.  This controller would likely call the builder whenever it needs to close a view and present a new view, and it would be the recipient of such events.